# Is there an API to fetch Apps status for Google workspace subscription?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-admin-settings-api

I'm in need of an API to

- Fetch available apps and their status for Org's workspace subscription
- Fetch user based usage stats for each apps associated to that particular subscription

Comment: Can you share more details on what are you asking? Do you mean: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest

Comment: @kessy I need to fetch all the apps available under a Google workspace subscription through api?
And I need an api to fetch last login time of users to each GSuite apps?

Comment: For the login you have the [Reports API: Login Activity Report](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-login) and for the apps available under subscription do you mean the [Enterprise License Manager API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/get-start/getting-started)?